# return _get_backend_mod().show(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: _Backend.show() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

How to fix these errors that are appearing again and again??????

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you [edit] your question and [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) it with the language and frameworks you are using.  Doing so makes it much more likely that experts in those tags will notice your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [matplotlib.pyplot.show()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib-pyplot-show) and [.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot) documents to know how to use them correctly.

You should use `plt.plot(x, y)` instead of `print(plt.show(x, y))`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 25)
y = x * x + 2
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```